# easy Method for drawing and moving a shape

Tags: java, graphics, draw

I am writing this method so when called it will cause a shape to draw and move. The draw part works already. I just need help with the moving part.

```
 public void moveAndDraw(Graphics window)
  {
    draw(window);
  }
```

Comment: How is `moveAndDraw` called, what does `draw` actually do...?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to have some way of storing the position of the object(perhaps a [java.awt.geom.Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html)). then you'd translate that point in your move. finally to show the move you'd call `window.translate(x,y)` to move your drawing center before you draw